# Collecting Load Weight Data From Linux Scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am working to understand the impact of different workloads on the load weight and WALT (ravg) in the linux scheduler. Specifically, I am working on the Android Kernel.

Currently, I am logging all of this data in an internal `struct` from inside the kernel. For the particular workload, I write the aforementioned data into the `struct` every time the `pick_next_task` is called.
As one would expect, the size of the logged data increases significantly within a short time period. Hence, I flush the data by writing it to file after the size of a log increases to a certain value.

I wanted to ask if there is another, better, way to log this time series data?
If not, then what would be a good way to stop the size of the log from exploding? Is there an alternative to writing the data to file? Would using debugfs be a better alternative?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish? Data needs to be stored somewhere. Whether you write it to file or keep it in RAM it will keep increasing regardless. Debugfs provides an interface to the user but the data still needs to be in RAM.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I'm trying to understand if there are patterns in the scheduler data that can be used to identify distinct phases in workloads, and later see if that information is useful for something. I understand that the data needs to live somewhere and I need RAM to accommodate it. But I can have different strategies to reduce the size of the data, e.g. random sampling during intervals etc. I'm just wondering what would be the best way to give the data to the user once it has been collected?